# Do I need to use the PWM pins in order to control brushless motors Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, drone

I am building a quadcopter with this schematic:
[image]

It works very good but i have the pins on 3,5,6,9 = PWM pins. Is it possible to use "regular" pins instead? I will add more modules later on so i will most likely run out of PWM pins.

I could of course try it right now but i want to ask first so i could potentially avoid to destroy any items!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you need to use PWM in order to control the ESCs which, in turn, control the motors. If you need more PWMs you might add daugtherboard based on other ICs which might provide additional PWM outputs via I2C or serial interface.

In some non critical conditions (ESCs **are** critical for a quadcopter) you can simulate PWM by switching a plain digital pin HIGH and LOW very quickly, but that is not as reliable as using hardware PWM.

Comment: Damn it! I am missing 1 PWM then. I use this BLE device: https://learn.adafruit.com/getting-started-with-the-nrf8001-bluefruit-le-breakout/hooking-everything-up and if you check the schematic they require 3 PWM pins which means that there are only 3 left for my 4 motors. do you think i could change a PWM to a regular pin from that BLE device instead?

Comment: Ok i read it a bit more carefully now. Seems like i can change both REQ (pin 10) and RST (pin 9)  after i upload code if i am not mistaken

Comment: That's correct: they use pin 10 and pin 9 as plain digital, no PWM is required so by re-mapping those pins you can retain the PWM functionalities of pin 9 and 10 to your goals